# can iOS 6 lock different Orientations for different view controllers in UITabBarController?

Tags: ios6, uitabbar, uiinterfaceorientation

i meet a different issue in my app for iOS 6. i have a UITabBarController for the window's rootviewcontroller,and then i have 4 uiviewcontrollers in this tabbBarController, now i want twoof them is just display "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait",and the two others display in "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape", The problem is that when I tap from the one which display in  "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait" to the other viewController which is UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape , however the new selected viewcontroller  is still "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait" ,but when i rotate the device, the new selected view controller is rotate to "UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape"  .....

so is there any way that can make the tabbarviewcontroller  can autorotate when I tap the  different viewControllers?

below is my code:
1. I had alerady use the subclass of the UITabBarController in TR_UITabViewController.m

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return  [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
```

1. also in appdelegate.m I implement the method

   - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{
     NSUInteger orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

     if(self.window.rootViewController){
         UITabBarController *presentedViewController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;
         UIViewController * currentVC=presentedViewController.selectedViewController;

     ```
     NSLog(@"currentVC info:%@",[currentVC description]);
     if ([currentVC isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]]) {
         orientations = [currentVC supportedInterfaceOrientations];
        // self.tabBarController.=[currentVC supportedInterfaceOrientations];

     } else if([currentVC isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {

         UINavigationController * nvc=(UINavigationController*)currentVC;
         UIViewController * vc=nvc.topViewController;

      orientations = [vc supportedInterfaceOrientations];
     }
     ```

     }

     return orientations;
     }

3.at last I have write the below two method in each view controller
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate ; & 
- (NSUInteger) supportedInterfaceOrientations

In ,worlds, can someone know that how to force change the  Orientation when tap the different view controllers in tabbarviewcontroller?